# How to use pybluez and kivy for android development?

Tags: android, kivy

I'm developing an android application which has a dependency on pybluez, the problem is that when I launch my application, kivy launcher/logcat complains about pybluez is compiled for x86, not ARM:

ImportError: dlopen failed: "/storage/emulated/0/kivy/orkiv/bluetooth/_bluetooth.so" not 32-bit: 2

Do you know how to solve this? I think that I have to compile it for ARM... but need some guidance on this because I've never done it before. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As per my answer on the kivy mailing list:

> I'm not sure pybluez will actually work on android? You'd need to use
>   the android apis to access the bluetooth device.
>
> Either way, how did you compile it for android?

You would access the android apis via pyjnius, or hopefully it will soon have a cross platform python api via kivy's [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) project.

Edit: It looks like pybluez is really a wrapper to the bluez c library. You would need to make a python-for-android recipe to compile this for android, even if it does have a way to access bluetooth on android.

Comment: You mean that there isn't a way to use pybluez in android? Im not interested in using android api via pyjnius unless it is the only option. Thank you

Comment: I don't know if bluez supports android, but I wouldn't bet on it. I could be wrong though, it's not impossible.

Comment: I believe android *previously* used bluez but replaced it with broadcomm's bluedroid around Android 4.2  If you have a custom device you can perhaps switch back, but that would be difficult on a typical locked-down consumer device where you are basically limited to official APIs (plus various questionable-future loose ends that don't require unavailable additional permissions, such as access to raw device nodes).

Comment: I've found this: https://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/downloads/detail?name=PyBluez-0.19-py2.6-linux-armv.egg the problem now is that it throws another error: ImportError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libpython2.6.so" needed by "_bluetooth.so"; caused by library "libpython2.6.so" not found... I've googled about libpython2.6.so and it seems to be a library from py4a.... I'll tell you if i find an answer

Comment: That's actually the wrong python-for-android, kivy's one is [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android), though I suppose the existence of that egg means compiling pybluez is probably possible. Although as per what Chris Stratton says, I'm not sure this is a good route to reliably using bluetooth.